# NPM install behind company's network settings

Tags: node.js, npm

I am running `npm install` behind my corporate VPN and I am getting the following error:

```
request to http://registry.npmjs.org/yarn failed, reason: getaddrinfo 
EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/yarn failed, reason: 
connect ETIMEDOUT 104.17.19.33:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network 
settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\blah\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09- 
24T14_21_25_097Z-debug.log
```

I tried the following methods and none of them resolved it:

```
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy

npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

I am unable to install any packages and not sure how to fix it?

---

How do I find my proxy address?

Comment: To find the proxy address, you have to ask the administrator of your network

Comment: Are you able to access the internet from your browser? If yes, then in your browser(IE) go to tools - > internet options-> Connections - > Lan settings - you will either find the proxy address there or a Link which will provide the proxy address.